# Why does Date().getHours() sometimes return a boolean of True?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script to try and send automatic emails during business hours.  As part of this, I use some of the Date functions to get the current day, hour, minute, etc.

```
  var nowH=new Date().getHours();
  var nowD=new Date().getDay();
  var nowM=new Date().getMinutes();
  Logger.log('Day: ' + nowD + ', Hour: ' + nowH + ', Min: ' + nowM )
```

When I run this, it runs fine. For example, it currently returns:

```
[18-10-04 13:18:02:743 AEST] Day: 4, Hour: 13, Min: 18
```

So it looks like it's working fine, but when I use my if statements, the timing seems off.  I decided to print some of these in the HTML email as well:

```
+ '<br>Debug: Day: ' + nowD + '  Hour: ' + nowH + '  Min:  ' + nowM
```

And to my surprise, I get something like:

```
Debut: Day: 4 Hour: true Min: 18
```

So it looks like the 'nowH' hour data, has suddenly turned into 'True'.  I don't reference nowH any other time before the if-statement or adding this to the email.

Are there any obvious reasons how this might change to a boolean?

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or some code to try and reproduce this behavior?

Comment: nope, it never does

Comment: `before the if-statement` - show the if statement ... I suspect you are using `=` instead of `==` or `===` somewhere

Comment: Ahh interesting - here is the if statement:

if((nowH=10 && nowM > 25 && nowM < 35 && nowD!=6 && nowD!=0 ) || (nowH>=10 && nowH<=17 && nowM <5 && nowM>58 && nowD!=6 && nowD!=0))

Basically I'm trying to send it at 10:30am, and then at every o'clock (11pm, 12pm, 1pm, 2pm, 3pm, 4pm, 5pm) and then stop. For every weekday.

Comment: `10 && nowM > 25 && nowM < 35 && nowD!=6 && nowD!=0` is probably true ... `if ((nowH == 10 && .....` will fix you up

Comment: Oh right, so even though it's within the if statement, the nowH is actually being changed to equal something else?  As opposed to comparing?

Comment: Ahh, it works!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jaromanda X, it was the single = sign which seemed to change the value of 'nowH'.

I tested this by adding a separate logger of the same 3 fields.

Before the change:
if((**nowH=10** && nowM > 25 && nowM < 35 && nowD!=6 && nowD!=0 ) || (nowH>=10 && nowH<=17 && nowM <5 && nowM>58 && nowD!=6 && nowD!=0))

> [18-10-04 13:47:02:337 AEST] Day: 4, Hour: 13, Min: 47
>
> [18-10-04 13:47:02:338 AEST] Day2: 4, **Hour2:** **false**, Min2: 47

After the change:
if((**nowH==10** && nowM > 25 && nowM < 35 && nowD!=6 && nowD!=0 ) || (nowH>=10 && nowH<=17 && nowM <5 && nowM>58 && nowD!=6 && nowD!=0))

> [18-10-04 13:47:02:337 AEST] Day: 4, Hour: 13, Min: 47
>
> [18-10-04 13:47:02:338 AEST] Day2: 4, **Hour2: 13**, Min2: 47